# translation rotation matrix

Tags: matrices

I have been trying to get a rotation translation matrix working. It worked for a couple of times but seems to be giving the wrong results now.

The matrix I am using is

[image]

my initial $x,y,z$ locations are $(628.12, 265.00, 0)$.
My offset vectors after movements are $(-84.73, 57.91, 0)$ and rotation angle $-2.22$ degrees. This is how far they have moved in each direction / axis.

When input into my transformation matrix they look like this

[image]

And get the following:
$(646.74, 77.94)$
When I am expecting $(712.85, 207.09, 0)$ - I think.

As you can see, these are very different. Could somebody please shed some light on this?

I'm wondering whether it has something to do with the fact that my coordinate system from $(0,0)$ is negative $y$ when travelling up and positive $y$ when travelling down and positive $x$ to the right, negative $x$ to the left. I changed the $\pm$ signs in front of the $\sin(\theta)$ but didn't really get much better results.

Comment: Your values for $\sin\theta$ and $\cos\theta$ are wrong: you should check that, I think.

Comment: Ahh! It seems I had a typo. It should have been 0.039 in the sin boxes. https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/15501961/matrixNumbersTypo.JPG

Comment: Thanks Aretino, I just managed to find that. Annoying mistake cost me 2 hours tracing it through. I thought the Cos was correct though. I just rounded of 0.99 to 1.0. Am I wrong?

Comment: It all depends on the precision you need, in this case it shouldn't make a big difference.